# How can I convert a pgn file into a text, word, or pdf file?

Tags: pgn, recommendations

I want to convert a pgn file into a text, word, or pdf file so I can export games in a pgn file format. I either need software or a link to an online tool. Does anyone know of such a tool?

Comment: I think I'm confused. You want to turn a PGN file into a text file? How does the PGN file not already meet your needs in that regards?

Answer (score 2):

A pgn file is simply a text file.  If you change the ".txt" extension to ".pgn", you have a pgn file.
Once it's in a txt file, it's well-known how to convert into the other two formats.